# Get overlap of two queries from one table

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to find if these two queries have an overlap

The following PHP/MYSQL code works, however it is clunky; two queries, data is converted into arrays, arrays are compared!

(Notice this is a function as it returns whether there is an overlap)

```
$manager_sql = "SELECT league_id FROM league_members WHERE manager = 1 AND member_active = 1 AND player_id = $mi";
$player_sql = "SELECT league_id FROM league_members WHERE member_active = 1 AND player_id = $pi";

$manager_result = mysql_query($manager_sql) or die(mysql_error());
$manager_leagues = array();
while($sqlrow = mysql_fetch_array($manager_result)) {
    extract( $sqlrow );
    $manager_leagues[] = $league_id;
}

$player_result = mysql_query($player_sql) or die(mysql_error());
$player_leagues = array();
while($sqlrow = mysql_fetch_array($player_result)) {
    extract( $sqlrow );
    $player_leagues[] = $league_id;
}

$result = array_intersect($manager_leagues, $player_leagues);

return count($result) > 0;
```

Here are some attempts at doing the query in one go:

```
(SELECT league_id FROM league_members WHERE manager = 1 AND member_active = 2 AND player_id = '$mi')
    UNION ALL
(SELECT league_id FROM league_members WHERE member_active = 1 AND player_id = '$pi')
```

Seems to work, but returns too many rows:

```
SELECT league_id FROM league_members WHERE league_id IN (
    SELECT league_id FROM league_members WHERE manager = 1 AND member_active = 1 AND player_id = '$mi'
) AND league_id IN (
    SELECT league_id FROM league_members WHERE member_active = 1 AND player_id = '$pi'
)
```

Comment: by overlap, you mean what?

Comment: if you just check for `$pi` in the first query, it'd be the same thing.

Comment: A $mi manages a bunch of leagues (eg 2,4,6) and a $pi plays in a bunch of leagues (eg 1,3,7) - the overlap is comparing 2,4,6 with 1,3,7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query :

```
$sql = "SELECT ls1.league_id FROM league_members AS ls1
        INNER JOIN league_members AS ls2 ON ls1.league_id = ls2.league_id
        WHERE ls1.manager = 1 AND ls1.member_active = 1 AND ls1.player_id = '".$mi."' 
        AND ls2.member_active = 1 AND ls2.player_id = '".$pi."'"
```

NOTE :

1. mysql_* functions are deprectated, use mysqli_* functions or PDO
2. Your query is vulnerable to sql injection, make it seccure.

Comment: His query isn't necessarily vulnerable, it depends on where the data for $mi and $pi are coming from.  If, say, they've been cast to (int)s, then injection shouldn't be a problem.  But I agree it's poor practice as is.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. $mi and $pi can only be integers, and therefor safe. (famous last words)

Comment: On the other side, just because you believe `$mi` and `$pi` can only be integers doesn't make it so, you must enforce that constraint.  What I'm saying is, your application is probably OK today, but as things change over time you might change the source of `$mi` and `$pi` from what it is now to a less trusted source, and if you haven't enforced the integer constraint explicitly in the code, you might forget to do so at that time.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to find any league_id's that have both `$mi` as the manager and `$pi` as one of the players?

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.league_id FROM league_members l JOIN league_members l2 ON l.league_id = l2.league_id AND l.member_active = 1 AND l2.member_active = 1 AND l.manager = 1 AND l2.manager = 0 WHERE l.player_id = $mi AND l2.player_id = $pi;
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
"SELECT league_id FROM league_members WHERE manager = 1 AND member_active = 1 AND (player_id = '".$mi."' OR player_id = '".$pi."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below it would be worked. If not then please let me know which kinda problem you'r getting.

SELECT league_id FROM league_members WHERE league_id IN (
    SELECT league_id FROM league_members WHERE (member_active = 1 AND (player_id = '$mi' or  player_id = '$pi') AND manager = 1)

Answer (score 0):

I obviously haven't tried this, but I'd suggest the last query, with the `distinct` keyword added:

```
SELECT distinct league_id FROM league_members WHERE league_id IN (
    SELECT league_id FROM league_members WHERE manager = 1 AND member_active = 1 AND player_id = '$mi'
) AND league_id IN (
    SELECT league_id FROM league_members WHERE member_active = 1 AND player_id = '$pi'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
SELECT league_id 
FROM   league_members 
WHERE  (manager = 1 AND member_active = 1 AND player_id = $mi) OR
       (member_active = 1 AND player_id = $pi)
GROUP  BY league_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```